# FileSystemWatcher not firing events when office document saved

Tags: c#, .net, ms-office, filesystemwatcher

I am monitoring a directory and sub-directories for file changes using FileSystemWatcher, and process them by my windows application. I am using NotifyFilter CreationTime, LastWrite and Attributes when configuring the watcher. When a file is changed my app receive events. It works fine in almost all computers where my application is being used.

However, one of my colleague has got problem on his computer, where the files saved in monitored folder are not detected by my application. On further examination it turns out that only office files changes are not detected. Any non-office file type change raises events.

I am aware of behavior of different office application where files are saved as temporary file, copied, moved or renamed when the office document is being saved. I am ignoring them as i know names of files I am interested in. I can see that my application receive the notification of temporary files being changed but no notification about the actual file is being raised. Saving Document1.docx raises following events on this particular machine.

> Changed fp: C:\Files\Folder1 f:Folder1 nf:Attributes, LastWrite, CreationTime
>   Changed fp: C:\Files\Folder1 f:Folder1 nf:Attributes, LastWrite, CreationTime
>   Changed fp: C:\Files\Folder1\~$cument1.docx f:Folder1\~$cument1.docx nf:Attributes, LastWrite, CreationTime
>   Changed fp: C:\Files\Folder1 f:Folder1 nf:Attributes, LastWrite, CreationTime
>   Changed fp: C:\Files\Folder1\~WRD0000.tmp f:Folder1\~WRD0000.tmp nf:Attributes, LastWrite, CreationTime
>   Changed fp: C:\Files\Folder1\~WRD0000.tmp f:Folder1\~WRD0000.tmp nf:Attributes, LastWrite, CreationTime
>   Changed fp: C:\Files\Folder1\~WRD0000.tmp f:Folder1\~WRD0000.tmp nf:Attributes, LastWrite, CreationTime
>   Changed fp: C:\Files\Folder1\~WRD0000.tmp f:Folder1\~WRD0000.tmp nf:Attributes, LastWrite, CreationTime
>   Changed fp: C:\Files\Folder1\~WRD0000.tmp f:Folder1\~WRD0000.tmp nf:Attributes, LastWrite, CreationTime
>   Changed fp: C:\Files\Folder1 f:Folder1 nf:Attributes, LastWrite, CreationTime
>   Changed fp: C:\Files\Folder1 f:Folder1 nf:Attributes, LastWrite, CreationTime
>   Changed fp: C:\Files\Folder1\~WRL0001.tmp f:Folder1\~WRL0001.tmp nf:Attributes, LastWrite, CreationTime
>   Changed fp: C:\Files\Folder1 f:Folder1 nf:Attributes, LastWrite, CreationTime

I created a little app to test the changes by modifying various notify filters and event types. It turns out that as soon as I add NotifyFilters.Security it starts raising event for actual document too.

I am not sure why it is happening on this particular computer. The problem computer is a windows 8.1 laptop with bitlocker on it. Same app works fine one other similar laptops with same OS and bitlocker.

It is a really easy fix to add NotifyFilters.Security but I am keen on knowing why it matters. Any ideas what might be the reason?

Comment: I was having exactly the same problem. I don't know either why this happens, I agree with you when you say that this might have something to do with the creation of temporary files that Office does. However, considering that there is no valid response for which to vote, thanks for the quickfix concerning **NotifyFilters.Security**.